# get handles count associated to a kernel object (win 32 application)

Tags: file, winapi, count, mapping, handle

I'm developing a simple win32 application with two processes sharing memory through a file mapping. At a certain point in the second process, I want to check if the other process has already closed the handle associated to the file mapping.
Is there a Windows function to retrieve the number of handles associated to my shared memory???
Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the API to do that. If you want to know when the other process has finished its work, create a manual reset event with [CreateEventEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and have the other process set the event when its work is done. The first process can use one of the [wait functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to query the status of the event.